# Float conversion failing in for loop (python)

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I'm trying to extract anomalous data points from a large csv file (~1e6 lines) in which most of the data points are at constant value. I've written the code below to detect values lower than the constant.

```
constant = 1
try:
    fp = open('disk2.csv')
    for line in fp: 
        ch4 = float(line.split(",")[4]) #data from channel four is in the fifth column
        if ch4 < constant:
            print line.split(",")[0] #print first column

except:
    ch4 = 'Not found'
finally:
    fp.close()
    print(ch4,type(ch4))
```

the print returns the following, without additional errors:

```
('Not found', <type 'str'>)
```

if I change the code to:

```
constant = 1
try:
    fp = open('disk2.csv')
    for line in fp: 
        ch4 = line.split(",")[4] #data from channel four is in the fifth column
        if ch4 < constant:
            print line.split(",")[0] #print first column

except:
    ch4 = 'Not found'
finally:
    fp.close()
    print(ch4,type(ch4))
```

It returns

```
(' 2.41650E+01', <type 'str'>)
```

So, the csv file is read as a string, and the string can be divided into a list using the split command, but I cannot turn the items in the list into floating numbers?

### The error was not in the code but in my CSV file, which did not contain enough items on the first row

Comment: You can change the string into a float using `float_value = float(ch4)`

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question so I'm not including it as an answer, but you might take a look at using the pandas library if you'll be working much with csv data.  This could be done in 2 lines with the first being reading the file into a DataFrame and the second showing all rows with value less than constant.

Comment: would it also work for a CSV file with millions of lines?

Comment: pandas would load the whole thing into memory, so as long as you have enough memory you should be fine.  There's another library called dask that uses the pandas API but allows for using data sets that don't fit into memory, but I've never used it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, you are doing the comparison with the values, and changing the format from `str` to `float` for the comparison, as in `if float(ch4) < constant`. Note that you are not storing the value as a `float` type, but just converting it right there for this particular evaluation.

In the second case, you are comparing a `str` and an `int`. Notice that when you use `constant = 1`, the type for constant by default is `int`, and not `float`. Having said that, you are comparing an `int` and a `str`. For this evaluation, your code would compare the values by encoding the string as such into `int`. For example, in ASCII, 'A' would be encoded as 65. The string would be converted into the integer representation, depending on the encoding used, and then would be used for the evaluation.

To solve your problem, you must store the value in `ch4` as a `float`. This can be done by `ch4 = float(line.split(",")[4])` which will store the value in a `float` variable, as opposed to the `str` variable.

Comment: If I change line 5 to `ch4 = float(line.split(",")[4]` then I get the same result as in the first example. Do you have an example of how it would work?

Comment: you need to end the braces well. Are you sure it's not a typo? In the block itself, you can do a `print(type(ch4))` to verify if it works

Comment: when I request the type inside the for loop, it works when the code is `ch4 = line.split(",")[4]` but not when the code is `ch4 = float(line.split(",")[4])` (indeed above there was a typo, but that was not in the real code.)

Comment: According to the numbers you provided in another answer, and when I evaluated them with `ch4 = float(blah)`, and it displays the `type(ch4)` as `float`. The condition says that the number is supposed to be less than 1, and so it displays the part in `finally` block. The number in question for the evaluation is 2.41900E+01. If i change the value of constant to 25, it displays the first column as a string (we didn't typecast it), and the final value of `ch4`, and it's type. Isn't that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: You are right and it turned out I had missed that the top row of my file was unsuited for this way of reading out...

Comment: Glad to help, please mark the answer as accepted to close the question thread if it answers your question to your satisfaction. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a bad practice to directly compare floats. it's better to use something like this:

`abs(float(ch4), constant) <= allowed_error`

Where allowed_error is some small value like 0.000001, for example. Floating point numbers are stored differently from integers and 1.0 can internally be 0.9999999 or 1.000001.

Comment: In case where they need to be ranked, is there some way to generate the value of allowed_error for 16 decimal places, for example?

Comment: You can use sys.float_info.epsilon for that, I believe.

Comment: This looks like a way to find small differences between numbers. I'm actually looking for a bigger difference, but the allowed_error value could be used to tune that. Anyway, I changed line 6 to `abs(float(ch4),constant) <= allowed_error` with `allowed_error` set to 0.1 and it generated the same result (i.e. the for loop is failing)

Comment: Can you show a sample of your file? A couple of lines? Can you temporarily change constant to something that's definitely bigger than some values in that sample and try again?

Comment: Most lines look like this `1.320460000E+04, 2.41900E+01, 2.41900E+01, 2.41900E+01, 2.41900E+01, 2.41900E+01, 2.50000E-02, 2.00000E-02, 2.40000E-01, 1.00000E-02,-2.36750E+01,0, \n`

Comment: So in the column of interest the value is typically a little ~24.2 and I am looking for moments when this value is close to zero. I changed `constant` to 25 and still go the same result. It seems to me that the for loop is not running whenever I put the `float()` function in it...

Comment: Here I've made a simple file disk2.csv like yours:

1,2,3,4,2.50000E-02\n
2,2,3,4,2.50000E+02\n
3,2,3,4,2.50000E-02\n
4,2,3,4,2.50000E+02\n
5,2,3,4,2.50000E-02\n
6,2,3,4,2.50000E-02\n

Now I run your script:

`$ python stackoverflow_1.py 

1\n
3\n
5\n
6\n
('2.50000E-02\n', <type 'str'>)`\n

Comment: ...As it turns out, the first line of my .csv file has only 3 items in the list. After removing the first line, my original code works. Should I delete the question? I did learn about string conversion and comparing floats...